# Indexing with pointer C/C++

Tags: c

Hey I'm trying to write a program to carry out newtons method and find the roots of the equation exp(-x)-(x^2)+3. It works in so far as finding the root, but I also want it to print out the root after each iteration but I can't get it to work, Could anyone point out my mistake I think its something to do with my indexing?

Thanks a million :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <malloc.h>

//Define Functions:
double evalf(double x)
{
        double answer=exp(-x)-(x*x)+3;
        return(answer);
}
double evalfprime(double x)
{
        double answer=-exp(-x)-2*x;
        return(answer);
}
double *newton(double initialrt,double accuracy,double *data)
{
        double root[102];
        data=root;
        int maxit = 0;
        root[0] = initialrt;
        for (int i=1;i<102;i++)
        {
                *(data+i)=*(data+i-1)-evalf(*(data+i-1))/evalfprime(*(data+i-1));
                if(fabs(*(data+i)-*(data+i-1))<accuracy)
                {
                        maxit=i;
                        break;
                }
                maxit=i;
        }

        if((maxit+1==102)&&(fabs(*(data+maxit)-*(data+maxit-1))>accuracy))
        {
                printf("\nMax iteration reached, method terminated");
        }      
        else
        {
                printf("\nMethod successful");
                printf("\nNumber of iterations: %d\nRoot Estimate: %lf\n",maxit+1,*(data+maxit));
        }

        return(data);
}




int main()
{
    double root,accuracy;
    double *data=(double*)malloc(sizeof(double)*102);

    printf("NEWTONS METHOD PROGRAMME:\nEquation: f(x)=exp(-x)-x^2+3=0\nMax No iterations=100\n\nEnter initial root estimate\n>> ");
    scanf("%lf",&root);
    _flushall();
    printf("\nEnter accuracy required:\n>>");
    scanf("%lf",&accuracy);
    *data= *newton(root,accuracy,data);
    printf("Iteration        Root           Error\n ");
    printf("%d          %lf             \n", 0,*(data));
    for(int i=1;i<102;i++)
    {
        printf("%d             %5.5lf           %5.5lf\n", i,*(data+i),*(data+i)-*(data+i-1));
        if(*(data+i*sizeof(double))-*(data+i*sizeof(double)-1)==0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    getchar();
    getchar();
    free(data);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: How the heck this question is related to its title?!

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: because im sure my problem is related to indexing into my array with pointers

Comment: It prints out the correct root but when I try to list all roots during the newtons method process it gives zeros for all the roots except the first in the list,

Answer (score 1):

No offenses, but your question is highly seductive to downvoting. Unrelated question title, ridiculous coding style (I mean tabulation).

Also within your `newton` function there's no actual need to store all the intermediate results, the Newton-Raphson should not use extra memory (i.e. it's O(1)).

Just add `printf` within your `newton` inside the iteration loop. Is this a problem?

Comment: Sorry I don't mean to falsly advertise the question. I've only been coding for 2months so my style isn't great.

Answer (score 1):

In `newton`, you are returning the address of a local variable that doesn't exist anymore after the function returns. Accessing it afterwards is undefined behaviour.

In `main` you have

```
if(*(data+i*sizeof(double))-*(data+i*sizeof(double)-1)==0)
```

`data` is a `double*`, so `data + i` addresses the i-th `double` from the start. By multiplying the offset with `sizeof(double)`, you access beyond the end of the array if `i > number_of_elements/sizeof(double)`, yet more undefined behaviour.

And, thanks to JeremyP for finding it, in `main` you call `newton`

```
*data= *newton(root,accuracy,data);
```

which dereferences the pointer returned by `newton` (undefined behaviour, but at that point likely to do what you want) and stores that value in the first slot of the `data` allocated in `main`. Sot that probably gives you the initial element of the `root` array from `newton`, but doesn't change anything else in the memory block allocated to `data` in `main`.

Comment: Also data+i*sizeof(double) should be data[i], using add and ptr dereference is an data+i*sizeof(double) unnecessary complication.

Comment: Just noticed, this line in main `*data= *newton(root,accuracy,data);` This assigns the first double in whatever newton returns to the first element of data.

Comment: Good find, @JeremyP. Totally overlooked that with the crappy indentation.

Comment: Sorry about the style, thank you very much for the help, I'll go back and fix the problems

Comment: @Leavenotrace I suspect at least half of the crappy indentation was due to you not yet knowing how to format code here. But do care about proper indentation, it's important for readability. Spend some time to acquire the habit while you're still fresh. Look how Roman formatted your code, that's good. And also heed Roman's advice from the comment here, use `data[i]` instead of `*(data+i)`, that's more readable and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

```
void newton(double initialrt,double accuracy,double *data)
{
    double root[102];
    data=root;
    // at this moment the values in the original argument data[]
    // are no longer accessible to this function.
    int maxit = 0;
    root[0] = initialrt;
    for (int i=1; i < 102; i++)
        {
                data[i] = data[i-1] 
                 - evalf(data[i-1]) / evalfprime( data[i-1] );
                if ( fabs(data[i] - data[i-1]) < accuracy )
                {
                        maxit=i;
                        break;
                }
                maxit=i;
        }

        if ( maxit+1 == 102 && fabs(data[maxit] - data[maxit-1] ) > accuracy )
        {
                printf("\nMax iteration reached, method terminated");
        }      
        else
        {
                printf("\nMethod successful");
                printf("\nNumber of iterations: %d\nRoot Estimate: %lf\n",maxit+1
                ,data[maxit);
        }
    return;
}
```

(this is merely a stylistic comment, since the real issues have already been addressed)

- pointer dereferencing and array indexing are equivalent in C. Your `*(data+i) = ...` is equivalent to `data[i] = ...`
- the return value is useless, the function could return instead something usefull (eg accuracy)
- return is not a function. No need to `return(something);` just `return something;` will do.
- you return a pointer to the local array root, which is out of scope when the caller sees it.
- whitespace makes a difference in reading experience

UPDATE: on second thought, I think in the inner loop the OP *intended* something like:

```
root[i] = root[i-1] 
        - evalf(data[i-1]) / evalfprime( data[i-1] );
if ( fabs(data[i] - data[i-1]) < accuracy )
     {
     maxit=i;
     break;
     }
maxit=i;
```